# Dell Studio XPS 1640 start up issues

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, laptop, reinstall

I've had a Dell Studio XPS 1640 Laptop for about 8 years. The last 4 years I've had issues with it's booting. It will start to load and then get the blue screen of death for a millisecond and instantly turn off. I've had success by reinstalling the operating system of Windows 7 with it's installation discs.

I've restored my computer before and that has also worked. However eventually, maybe a month or three it gets the same exact problem again.

It also has a bad battery, and can only power on when plugged in. I'm not worried about fixing that unless it may cause my current issue.

I have two operating discs, One Windows XP that the the computer came installed with and another Windows 7 Home Premium upgrade disc.

I aslo have the Drivers and Utilities disc that came preinstalled on the computer I bought from Dell. I've never used this disc before when restoring or resinstalling Windows.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated as I've searched high and low and received some help, but it seems the issue still comes back so far with everything I've attempted.

Comment: Will it boot and run with its battery removed? If so, pleas tape over the battery contacts with painter's tape or duct tape, and run with that so see if the dead cells in the battery pack are dragging down the CMOS battery and causing you to lose the CMOS configuration.

Comment: Yeah it still does the same issue with the battery removed.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but the problem is probably your hard disk. The blues screen of death can be caused by memory problems or by hardware failure. With time, hard disks develop bad sectors. Since the problem happens 3 months after a clean installation of windows, it is possible that the good sectors get clogged up in this period. Before I would suggest operating the laptop with a hard disk of a higher capacity, here are some things to do:

- Updating your BIOS
- Defragmenting your disk
- Formatting your disk

If the problem still persists, then replacing your hard disk would be essential.